# How to make stored procedure fail if condition is not met

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling

I need my stored procedure to fail if a condition is not met. In other words, I want to validate something, and if it's not validated, the procedure should end right there and fail.

Currently, the procedure does not fail if the condition is not met. It just doesn't go to the next step, but I want it to fail so I get notified.

It is fairly simple, but I am not that smart. Here is what I wrote:

```
declare @IncompleteRows int                                            
set @IncompleteRows = (select Count(*) from DimTable where Incomplete = 1)

if @IncompleteRows = 0

begin                                                                            
update DimTable2                                                               
set Column1 = 'X'                                                          
end
```

So, if @IncompleteRows = 0, then Table2 is updated as needed.
But if @IncompleteRows is not 0, nothing happens, and the stored procedure is       technically successful.

I want the stored procedure to fail. How can I do that? 
Thanks!

Comment: To John's point, below, you'll want to look into [Try/Catch/Throw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Aside from MSDN, there are plenty of other examples on the web for you to look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned before, you can throw an error anytime in the code. You can use either RAISERROR or THROW (which I believe it was implemented in 2012). You don't need the variable or the count either.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from DimTable where Incomplete = 1)
BEGIN                                                                            
    UPDATE DimTable2
    SET Column1 = 'X';
END 
ELSE
    RAISERROR('There are no rows in DimTable where Incomplete equals 1', --Message
            16, --Severity
            1); --State
```

Or

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from DimTable where Incomplete = 1)
BEGIN                                                                            
    UPDATE DimTable2
    SET Column1 = 'X';
END 
ELSE
    THROW 52000, --Error number must be between 50000 and  2147483647.
        'There are no rows in DimTable where Incomplete equals 1', --Message
        1; --State
```

You could also end the procedure without an error by using RETURN. If you return a value different to 0, you can use it as an indicator of some error in the application code.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from DimTable where Incomplete = 1)
BEGIN                                                                            
    UPDATE DimTable2
    SET Column1 = 'X';
END 
ELSE
    RETURN 10;
```

Comment: this is perfect! thanks so much. i thought it would be a lot more work, but i am clueless. i know my answers probably seem quite dumb. anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is `RAISERROR`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms178592(v=sql.100)

Something like this:

```
if @IncompleteRows = 0
  update DimTable2
     set Column1 = 'X';
else
  RAISERROR('I expected the query to return 0 records', 1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that really doesn't help me. I know I have to raise an error but I don't understand how, which is why I am asking. I never understand anything written by Microsoft.